# how to exclude a column from a MIN function depending on a column heading

Tags: excel

I have to find the minimum value from a data set of temperatures but one of the data columns is a reference probe which should not be included in the min function. i.e. I don't want the reference probe to print as the lowest value in the set.

At the moment I have a list of temperatures with a heading as an ID code, this ID code is defined as a ref probe in another sheet.

What I want to do is use the VLOOKUP function to get the ID code for the probe that is the reference, and then use this ID to exclude the column from the MIN function calculation.

I am sure there must be a way to do this but I just cant seem to find anything to help.

I was thinking of using the MATCH function to get the column number of the ID probe, which I can get to work, but once I have this value I am at a loss as to how to use that to exclude a specific column.

I have tried using this:

=MIN(C7:(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(7,(MATCH($CY$1,$A$3:$CX$3,0)-1),3,1))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(7,(MATCH($CY$1,$A$3:$CX$3,0)+1),3,1)):CX7)

Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated,

CB

EDIT:
I found a fix myself!
For those interested;
=MIN(C7:(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(7,(MATCH($CY$1,$A$3:$CX$3,0)-1),3,1))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(7,(MATCH($CY$1,$A$3:$CX$3,0)+1),3,1)):CX7)

The number 7 needed to be changed into a cell reference that changes as the rows go down so I did a sum with a reference number like so;

=MIN(C7:(INDIRECT(ADDRESS((A1+1),(MATCH($CY$1,$A$3:$CX$3,0)-1),3,1))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(A1+1),(MATCH($CY$1,$A$3:$CX$3,0)+1),3,1)):CX7)

Works a Treat!

Answer (score 0):

The number 7 needed to be changed into a cell reference that changes as the rows go down so I did a sum with a reference number like so;

=MIN(C7:(INDIRECT(ADDRESS((A1+1),(MATCH($CY$1,$A$3:$CX$3,0)-1),3,1))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(A1+1),(MATCH($CY$1,$A$3:$CX$3,0)+1),3,1)):CX7)